# aligning a responsive line

Tags: html, css

I'm building a responsive website and I want the behavior in this picture: 
[image]

as you see the line is centered and more specifically it's under the letters **out** of the about word I tried to have this by adding the `display:block` and the `margin:auto` to center the line, it worked but it didn't achieve what I'm aiming to (I want the line to be under the '**out**' letters), I have tried to position the line with adding a `margin-left` it worked too but it's not responive. any solutions?

here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<section class="about-us">
<h1 class="title"><i class="fas fa-utensils abicon"></i>
About us<div class="line"></div></h1>

  <p class="title-description">Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un
    imprimeur
    anonyme assembla </p>
</section>
```

**CSS**

```
  .about-us {
    color: black;
    font-family: Roboto;
    position: relative;
  }

  .title {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: text-bottom;

  }

.title::after{
  content:"";
    background-color: #ff9900;
  width: 50px;
  height: 4px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
display:block;
  margin:auto;
}

  .abicon {

    font-size: 2rem;

  }

  .title-description {
    display: block;
    margin: auto;
  }
```

this is a codepen snipet: https://codepen.io/Amoocris/pen/vPWOpX

By the way I know this is kind of stupid question but I'm still a CSS beginner,  I have tried the `align-text:center` and it didn't work I wanna know why and thank you in advance

Comment: Are you allowed to change the HTML?

Comment: Yes I'm allowed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very simple solution would be to wrap the characters "out" in a span.

```css
.about-us {
  color: black;
  font-family: Roboto;
  position: relative;
}

.title {
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: text-bottom;
}

.title .underline {
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ff9900;
}

.abicon {
  font-size: 2rem;
}

.title-description {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="about-us">
  <h1 class="title"><i class="fas fa-utensils abicon"></i> Ab<span class="underline">out</span> us
  </h1>

  <p class="title-description">Le Lorem Ipsum est simplement du faux texte employé dans la composition et la mise en page avant impression. Le Lorem Ipsum est le faux texte standard de l'imprimerie depuis les années 1500, quand un imprimeur anonyme assembla </p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're allowed to change the HTML you could use add a span around the letters "out" and then add the underline with pseudo elements:

```css
.underline {
  position: relative;
}

.underline:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 100%;
    height: 4px;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, orange, red);
    box-shadow: 0 0 2px 2px rgba(255, 0, 0, .2);
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
```

```html
<h1>Ab<span class="underline">out</span> us</h1>
```

EDIT:
I used pseudo elements instead of a border or a simple underline because it gives you more freedom in case you want to go crazy with effects like shadows, gradients, animations, ...